# Problem including Quill in Node.js project

Tags: node.js, express, quill

I'm working on a project with Node.js and Express.js.

I need to use [Quill](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) and I'm trying to include it from my ***node_modules*** folder. (Can't from [the CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quill/1.3.7/quill.min.js) because of Content Security Policy issue with nginx).

So, what I've done:

```
//index.js
app.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "node_modules", "quill"))
);
```

and

```
//page.ejs
<script type="module" src="/quill.js"></script>
```

So far, it works, as it includes ***node_modules/quill/quill.js*** successfully in the DOM but, it's showing 404 errors for all the other files within ***node_modules/quill*** folder which are being imported from ***node_modules/quill/quill.js*** file.

For example, these imports:

```
//node_modules/quill/quill.js

import Quill from './core';

import { AlignClass, AlignStyle } from './formats/align';
import { DirectionAttribute, DirectionClass, DirectionStyle } from './formats/direction';
import { IndentClass as Indent } from './formats/indent';

import Blockquote from './formats/blockquote';
import Header from './formats/header';
import List, { ListItem } from './formats/list';

import { BackgroundClass, BackgroundStyle } from './formats/background';
import { ColorClass, ColorStyle } from './formats/color';
import { FontClass, FontStyle } from './formats/font';
```

cause these errors in the browser console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/align:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/direction:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
> Found) /formats/indent:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/blockquote:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/background:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/list:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /formats/color:1
>
> ...
>
> ..
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 /formats/header:1

What am I doing wrong?
I'm open to any changes/suggestions on how to include this library (including from their CDN).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way.
just replace froala with quill.

```
app.use('/froalacss',express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/froala- editor/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css'));
app.use('/froalajs',express.static(__dirname+'/node_modules/froala- editor/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js'));
```